# I need a good MySQL database structure

Tags: mysql, database, layout, structure

I'm quite new to MySQL and do not really know how to create a good layout for the following setup:

A riddim (rythm) can hold several tunes (songs). A song has the following information/fields: name, artist, label, producer, last modified timestamp, year, lyrics, flag, tag, source.

A riddim has the fields name, last modified, genre, youtube and image.

Here is an illustration for better understanding:
http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/6553/93112345.png

If I put all the information in one table I will have redundant data (such as genre or image), as every row with an artist/tune would have the riddim (rythm) it was sung on in it.

Currently my tables look like the following:

RIDDIMS table:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| riddim        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| genre         | varchar(9)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| youtube       | varchar(11)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| image         | varchar(11)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| last_modified | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

TUNES table:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| riddim        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| artist        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| tune          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| label         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| producer      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| year          | varchar(4)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| lyrics        | text         | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| flag          | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| tag           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| source        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| last_modified | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

But I'm sure it is not a good layout. Do you guys have suggestions on how the tables/database structure should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the 'riddems' and 'tunes' in seperate tables is the right structure to use. Basically model your data as signular objects, if certain fields actually belong to two different objects, it should be in two different tables.

To connect the too tables together, on the table that belongs to the parent table (in this case a riddem has many tunes so tunes belongs to riddem) put a reference to the parents id field. So in this case the tunes table should have a field called 'riddem_id' which is set to the riddem the tune belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll change it to riddim_id and add a "name" field instead just like in the illustration above.

Answer (score 1):

The riddim field of the tunes table should be a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to the primary key of the riddims table. Generally it is not a good idea to use a text field as a primary key unless you are absolutely sure they will be unique. A safer option is to use a field called id, or riddim_id or something, which is a number with the AUTO_INCREMENT property set. That way every new item you add will be given its own unique key automatically. Then you set the foreign key to have the same value as the id of the linked record in the other table.

If you use this structure then you don't need to (and indeed shouldn't) duplicate any data. To find information about the riddim that a tune is in you do a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) in a select query.

Comment: And keep going with the normalization...  get 'artist', 'label', 'producer', etc., off into their own tables.

Comment: By that "normalization" you mean, make a table for each of those with a foreign key auto_increment id and the name?

Comment: Yes - although it's called the primary key of its own table, and a foreign key when referenced from another table.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) I'll try and stick to that, I just fear the queries are going to be rough for beginners then.

Comment: Okay, now I'm having a problem. Sometimes a "tune" has more than one artist, like "artist1 & artist2 - tune" -- I assume I have to add the artist "artist1 & artist2" in its own row into database.artists table? Or is there a better way to grab two artists into the foreign-keyed column "artist" in database.tunes?

Comment: If the artists only had one tune each then you could put the linking field in the artist table instead of the tunes table (a field in artist storing the id of the tune they are linked to). However if one artist can have many tunes and one tune many artists then you should use a linking table. So neither main table has a foreign key field, and you have a new table called tune_artist_link or whatever, which contains its own id, a tune id, and an artist id. That way you make an entry in that table for every connection between an artist and a tune. You'll have to do two joins in a select query...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not so different from other relational databases. So if you have some experience working with Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL you can use it in your design.

In your explanation you did not mention the possible parent-child relations between two tables. Is tunes table a parent of riddim table?

If it is true you have to use riddim field in the riddim table as foreign key pointing to the primary riddim field in the tunes table. You can have multiple riddim records referring to the one tunes record.

It is not obvious for me why image and youtube have 11 characters. If youtune field contains actual URL it needs more characters. Are you going to encode youtube and image fields using enumerators to avoid long strings?

Ask yourself how your typical search is going to perform? What is the most important field
to search for?

I am not sure why you use VARCHAR type for year field.SMALLINT would be sufficient and much more efficient for search as well as for storage. As a rule integer types are much more efficient for search operations.

Comment: Honestly saying I am totally new to databases at all. I guess that riddims is the parent to tunes, though I'm not quite sure yet what parent/child means, talking databases. 'image' has 11 characters because the images are saved to /images/covers/ and are randomly named (19283728374.jpg ie.). 'youtube' is 11 characters because the unique identifier for each youtube video is 11 characters long. The most important fields to search for are "riddim", "artist" and "tune". So I'm going to put those as indices. "year" is varchar(4) because it can also contain a year in the format "199x" or "198x".